# Javascript not following correct workflow

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

So, in Javascript i just did a simple loop that is supposed to call a fuction 3 times, but instead it executer everything inside the loop 3 times and only after that it calls the function 3 times. 
Any ideas of why this is happening

```js
 function latest_update() {
            for(var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
                var id = parseInt(document.getElementById("event_id"+i).innerHTML);
                alert("testing");
                document.getElementById("row_num").innerHTML = "" + i;
                FB.api("/" + id,
                    function (response) {
                        if (response && !response.error) {
                            var j = parseInt(document.getElementById("row_num").innerHTML);
                            alert(j);
                            document.getElementById("event_id"+j).innerHTML = response.name;
                        }
                    });
            }

        }
```

Comment: The code snippet isn't so helpful if it doesn't demonstrate the problem you have presented

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because of Javascript's single thread event loop, see:
http://blog.carbonfive.com/2013/10/27/the-javascript-event-loop-explained/

The JS thread must finish its current execution context (which is in this case, the for loop) before servicing the asynchronous FB functions which are queued up after the loop finishes.

Comment: Thanks ! do you know how i can get through this ?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to restucture your code. A great design pattern I use for HTTP requests is the promise pattern. Using promises you can implement your code to fire off the HTTP requests, wait for all the results to come in and then do something else. like so:

```
function doFBCall() {
  var promise = new Promise();
  FB.api('/' + id, function(response) {
    // do something
    ... 
    // Now resolve the promise
    promise.resolve(); 
    // Note: you should handle the error cases with promise.reject();
  });
  return promise;
};

var arrayOfPromises = [];
arrayOfPromises.push(doFBCall());
arrayOfPromises.push(doFBCall());
arrayOfPromises.push(doFBCall());

// Wait for all promises to finish
Promise.all(arrayOfPromises).then(function() {
  // All promises succeed
}).catch(function() {
  // One or more promises failed
});
```

Not sure if you are using a framework like Angular or Ember where a promise library is readily available.